# Destroy Gameobject according to distance value

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d, unityscript

I have a script that generates objects in the scene from a prefab, and I have a moveable cube. I want a script that gets the name of the object if the distance between the cube and the cloned object is < 0.3f.

I have this UnityScript:

```
var distance1 = Vector3.Distance(Food.transform.position, cube1.transform.position);
Debug.Log(distance1);

if(distance1 < 0.3f)
{
   //Destroy nearest object

}
```

Comment: What's the question ?

Comment: I want to destroy the nearest object ( < 0.3f )

Comment: The proper  tag for Unity3D is unity3d.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case I think is better to use Collision Detection as recommended by Barış Çırıka... but if you want to get it by distance I think you can do something like

```
var MyCube =  GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("MyCube");
LateUpdate(){
var distance = Vector3.Distance(this.gameObject.transform.position, MyCube.transform.position);
if(distance < 0.3f)
{
Destroy(this.gameObject);
}
}
```

this script should be attached to every object you instantiate.

Answer (score 0):

If you know which object is near. You can use [Destroy](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Destroy.html).

```
Destroy(cloneObject);
```

If you don't know which objects are near, you can use List to add clone objects 
and check it is near.(When you create clone you need to add clone to the list.)

You need to add `using System.Collections.Generic;` for using List.

Example code: (It's C# code but you can understand logic)

```
....
using System.Collections.Generic;
public List<GameObject>cloneObjectList;

private void cloneObject(){
  GameObject cloneObject = Instantiate(originalPrefab,position,rotation);
  cloneObjectList.add(cloneObject);
}

private void checkDistance(){
   foreach(GameObject cloneObject in cloneObjectList){
      float distance = Vector3.Distance(Food.transform.position, cloneObject.transform.position);
      if(distance <0.3f){
         cloneObjectList.Remove(cloneObject);
         Destroy(cloneObject);
      }
   }
}
```

Moreover you can use [Collision detection](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/2d/collider2d) system.